# Is there an info-graphic that explains java variable inheritance and constructor code flow?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

Is there an info-graphic that explains java variable inheritance and constructor code flow?

I'm having troubles visualizing how inheritance and class variables work, public, static private default or otherwise.

Comment: FWIW - I don't think you'll find an infographic on this

Comment: You're mixing up largely independent concepts here. Java packaging and access modifiers are a separate thing from inheritance, as is the class/instance distinction of the static keyword. There may be useful info-graphics for each separately but, especially for constructor code flow, there are subtleties (e.g. instance initialiser code blocks and chained constructors) which are probably best understood by seeing worked code examples. All depends what level of understanding you're expecting to get.

Comment: He's asking about info-graphics people! The answers so far are just explaining things textually. (Some of the linked-to stuff has pictures in, but they're not single-infographic-central, if you know what I mean.) Unfortunately I don't know of any such resources off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to go with [Lava Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) and try to write the code using above keywords and then test it.

1. **default:** Visible to the package. .
2. **private:** Visible to the class only
3. **public:** Visible to the world
4. **protected:**  Visible to the package and all subclasses .

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) from Oracle have a section all about Inheritance and should be able to answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier (public, protected, package) plays only a small role in inheritance.  You can't make a function or variable in a subclass less accessible than the superclass (e.g., Animal has public void doStuff() and Cat extends Animal has private void doStuff()

Static and non-static methods don't really affect inheritance either. Static variables work the same way, except relative to the class of interest

```
public class Magic{
    public static int pants;
}

public class MagicPants extends Magic{
    public void go(){
        System.out.println(pants); 
        System.out.println(MagicPants.pants);
        System.out.println(Magic.pants);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]){
        Magic.pants = 2;
        MagicPants.pants = 1;
        new MagicPants().go();
    }
}
```

All print 1

Constructor code flow is easy - follow the super() calls.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't know graphics.

Static means the variable is the same for all object which have the same class.

Like

```
public Class TryVariable{
    public static int variable = 2

    public static void main(String[] args){
        a = new TryVariable()
        b = new TryVariable()
        system.out.println(a.variable)
        system.out.println(b.variable)
        // both equals 2

        a.variable= 3
        system.out.println(a.variable)
        system.out.println(b.variable)
        // both equals 3, because variable is static. 
}
```

Public variable means you can directly change directly her by the way i do in ma previous example: object.variableName = value.
This is dangerous, all people inadvisable to use it.

Private variable can't be change directly you need to use somes getters and setters to do this work. It's is the good way to code.

The defaut, i'm not sur of all parameters so i don't describe to you. But 99.9% of time the private is use.

Protected mean, the variable is open to packages and sub classes (in first time private is easier to use and safer)

An other parameter can be final, with this parameter the variable can't be change any more. It's like a constant. And a static final parameter is a class constant.

If you need more information, previous response explain where are find the officials sources.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy example: http://vskl.blogspot.cz/2009/05/polymorphism-in-java.html

every time you create Circle or Square object, Shape object is created too

About the variables:
- `private` fields are not accessible by any other class including subclasses.
- `protected` fields are accessible by any subclass. Taken the picture from the link, variables x and y of abstract class Shape, every instance of Circle or Square have these fields.
- `default` fields are accessible by any subclass and by any class in the same package(only in same package, classes in subpackages do not have access). This is useful typicaly when writing automated test, you don't have to declare public getter for the field.
- `public` fields are accessible by any other class. However using those is not a clean way how to write code, it is better to create private field with getter and setter.
- `static` keyword designates field owned by class, not by it's instances. It is like having one field shared by multiple instances of the class. If one instance changes value of this field, every other instance can read only this new modified